# Problemas al Crear un registro con Go y Postgresql desde GORM Tipo de datos time.Time

Tags: postgresql, go

Cuando intento enviar información desde POSTMAN me genera un error con las fechas

**Linea de Error: err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&ente)**

**ERROR:**

{"message":"Error al leer los datos de los entes a registrar: parsing time \"2012-12-02\" as \"2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999-07:00\": cannot parse \"\" as \"T\"","code":400}

func EnteCreate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ente := models.Ente{}
    m := models.Message{}
    user := models.User{}

```
user, _ = r.Context().Value("user").(models.User)

err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&ente)
if err != nil {
    m.Message = fmt.Sprintf("Error al leer los datos de los entes a registrar: %s", err)
    m.Code = http.StatusBadRequest
    commons.DisplayMessage(w, m)
    return
}

ente.UserID = user.ID

db := configuration.GetConnection()
defer db.Close()

err = db.Create(&ente).Error
if err != nil {
    m.Message = fmt.Sprintf("Error al  crear el registro: %s", err)
    m.Code = http.StatusBadRequest
    commons.DisplayMessage(w, m)
    return
}

m.Message = "Ente creado con éxito"
m.Code = http.StatusOK
commons.DisplayMessage(w, m)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

El problema es al tratar de parsear la fecha del JSON a Time de golang el cual espera el formato RFC3339, la solucion mas sencilla es que envies la fecha en el formato esperado que es el que te muestra el error "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999-07:00" y no el que estas mandando "2006-01-02". De no ser posible entonces tienes que crear tu propio tipo de dato e implementar el MarshalJSON y el UnmarshalJSON de este tipo de dato para ser usado en tu modelo. Aqui puedes ver una respuesta a un problema parecido
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087960/json-unmarshal-time-that-isnt-in-rfc-3339-format